# Azure devops 2019.1 - Activity logs

Tags: security, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, diagnostics

I look for a way to collect and save activity and security logs from the Azure devops server(onprem 2019.1).

Logs include - user logins, build events, work item events, security changes etc.

I'm aware about this option https://server_name/tfs/_oi/_diagnostics/activityLog. But it's not an api interface.

Any Idea how it's can be implemented that?

Thanks.

Comment: The activity log is a view of the `tblCommand` table of the respective configuration and collection database. For on-premises installation that's the simplest way to programmatically query the activity logs.

Comment: @jessehouwing - firs of all thanks of your comment. I prefer to avoid runinng direct query against the DB(best practice aspect) That is not make sense that there is no simple way to achieve the logs.

Answer (score 1):

TFS keeps track of an activity log of all recent activities. This information is stored in 2 tables inside Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_collectionname called `tbl_Command` and `tbl_Parameter`. These tables keep a record of every single command that every single user has executed against TFS for the last 14 days.

If you don’t want to get activity log through `tbl_Command` table and hidden activity log page (http://server:port/tfs/_oi), I’m afraid there is no other way at present.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.